# Rails application self update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turnkeylinux.org

I have a rails application running on turnkey using debian 8. I've exported it as an appliance so depending on the computer the VM is running on, the IP address can change. I want a way that the rails application can self update when I push changes to git (gitlab), and run necessary migrations.

Comment: heard of https://jenkins.io ?

Comment: you need to use webhooks, so gitlab would send a request to deployment service when a push occurs, that deployment service would do a deploy. The other way I can think of is to have the CI server deploy when all tests pass, this is probably safer. Or I believe Heroku has something similar built in, but I have never used it. 
If you want self-hosted CI https://drone.io is good.

Comment: @PamioSolanky, I'll check it out.

Comment: @Kris, thanks. I'll look it up